# stream audio over wifi

Tags: sound

I want to stream my audio output over the network (Wi-Fi) to my Android devices. I'm not looking for a music/video streaming solution, but I would stream any audio output of my GNU/Linux desktop to my Android work like a bluetooth headphone.
Ubuntu 16.04
Im very new so please go easy one me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to go about that and most, if not all require matching, software on both the Lunix and Android devices. There is a very extensive and straight-forward article about one of your options at [THIS LINK](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-stream-audio-your-linux-pc-android) called SoundWire posted on LiNUX.COM.

Comment: soundwire needs a server , the free version stops after 45 minutes. It is some binary file and they do not provide sourcecode. So, don't use it if you care about security!